# Stored procedure throws an error while getting data from two table using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which are shown in this screenshot:

[image: see image here]

I am writing a stored procedure which will return data from both tables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryDetails] 
    @MaterialId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tms.Material_ID AS MaterialId,
        tmm.Name As MaterialName,
        CONVERT(varchar,Quantity) AS AddedQuantity, 
        UtilizedQuantity ='-',
        tcl.LedgerName AS SupplierName,
        UsedFor = '-',
        tmm.CurrentStock,
        tmm.OpeningStock,
        CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), tms.Material_Date, 112)) AS MaterialDate,
        tms.Narration AS Narration
    FROM 
        tblMaterialSheet tms 
    JOIN 
        tblMaterialMaster tmm ON tmm.Material_ID = tms.Material_ID
    JOIN  
        tblCompanyLedger tcl ON tcl.Pk_LedgerId = tms.Ledger_ID
    WHERE 
        tms.Material_ID = @MaterialId 
        AND tms.isActive = 1

UNION 

SELECT 
    tmu.Material_ID AS MaterialId,
    tmm.Name As MaterialName,
    AddedQuantity = '-',
    CONVERT(varchar,Utilized_Quantity) AS UtilizedQuantity,
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Utilization_Date, 112)) AS MaterialDate,
    SupplierName = '-',
    tbst.Name AS UsedFor,
    tmm.CurrentStock,
    tmm.OpeningStock,
    tmu.Narration As Narration
FROM 
    tblMaterialUtilization tmu 
JOIN 
    tblMaterialMaster tmm ON tmm.Material_ID = tmu.Material_ID
JOIN 
    tblBuildingSubTask tbst ON tbst.BuildingSubTask_ID = tmu.BuildingSubTask_ID
WHERE 
    tmu.Material_ID = @MaterialId
    AND tmu.isActive = 1
END
```

When I call the stored procedure, it throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Table structure: `tblmaterialsheet`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMaterialSheet]
(
    [MaterialSheet_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BuildingSubTask_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Material_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Material_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Unit_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Size_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Height] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [Width] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [Rate_Per_Unit] [money] NULL,
    [Paid_Amount] [money] NULL,
    [Total_Amount] [money] NULL,
    [Vehical_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Ledger_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Narration] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Challan_No] [int] NULL,
    [Bill_ID] [int] NULL,
    [isBilled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Approval] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Approval_ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UploadImage] [image] NULL,
    [isActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Table structure : `tblMaterialUtilization`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMaterialUtilization]
(
    [MaterialUtilization_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [User_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BuildingSubTask_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Material_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Utilization_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Utilized_Quantity] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Narration] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

Table structure :  `tblMaterialMaster`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblMaterialMaster]
(
    [Material_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Unit_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [OpeningStock] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [PurchaseLedger] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [CurrentStock] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
)
```

Table structure : `tblBuildingSubTask`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBuildingSubTask]
(
    [BuildingSubTask_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BuildingTask_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [Narration] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TargetCompletionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ActualCompletionDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Provide us with the structure of the tables into text format.

Comment: updated question please refer question again

Comment: `Invalid object name 'tblMaterialMaster` & `tblBuildingSubTask`, append the structure of `tblMaterialMaster`& `tblBuildingSubTask`.

Comment: `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: updated question @ ahmed abdelqader

Comment: Please append all required tables, the query is selecting  from 5 tables > `tblMaterialSheet` ,`tblMaterialMaster` ,`tblCompanyLedger` ,`tblMaterialUtilization`  &`tblBuildingSubTask`

Comment: Answer Given by @Susang worked for me by changing order of columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRY THIS NOW:** The order of the column were not in the same order so it was getting the different datatype values for the same column. Datatype and Order is most important in the UNION

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryDetails] 
@MaterialId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    tms.Material_ID AS MaterialId,
    tmm.Name As MaterialName,
    CONVERT(varchar,Quantity) AS AddedQuantity, 
    UtilizedQuantity ='-',
    tcl.LedgerName AS SupplierName,
    UsedFor='-',
    tmm.CurrentStock,
    tmm.OpeningStock,
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), tms.Material_Date, 112)) AS MaterialDate,
    tms.Narration As Narration
        FROM 
            tblMaterialSheet tms 
            JOIN tblMaterialMaster tmm on tmm.Material_ID = tms.Material_ID
            JOIN tblCompanyLedger tcl on tcl.Pk_LedgerId = tms.Ledger_ID
        WHERE 
            tms.Material_ID = @MaterialId 
        AND 
            tms.isActive = 1
UNION 
    SELECT 
    tmu.Material_ID AS MaterialId,
    tmm.Name As MaterialName,
    AddedQuantity = '-',
    CONVERT(varchar,Utilized_Quantity) AS UtilizedQuantity,
    SupplierName = '-', --Moved up
    tbst.Name AS UsedFor, --Moved up
    tmm.CurrentStock, --Moved up
    tmm.OpeningStock, --Moved up
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Utilization_Date, 112)) AS MaterialDate,
    tmu.Narration As Narration
        FROM 
            tblMaterialUtilization tmu 
            JOIN tblMaterialMaster tmm on tmm.Material_ID = tmu.Material_ID
            JOIN tblBuildingSubTask tbst on tbst.BuildingSubTask_ID = tmu.BuildingSubTask_ID
        WHERE 
            tmu.Material_ID = @MaterialId
        AND 
            tmu.isActive = 1
END
```

Comment: Changed order as you have said ..your trick worked for me.. perfect answer ...Thank you @Susang

Answer (score 2):

The troubleshooting direction I'd take:

Look at your SQL. You're looking for anything that might be converting something of non-date type to date type. Your error probably means there's data somewhere you're converting to date that can't be converted. Be aware that this can include comparisons or functions that output a date.

Looking at your example, without knowing that actual data types, the only place I can see this happening is the explicit CONVERT functions on tms.Material_Date and Utilization_Date. I'd quickly comment these out and run each of the halves of the UNION separately. If they work, I could uncomment one or other until I figure out which field is causing the error. If they work independently but not unioned, I know that it's the after-union fields getting converted to date because the pre-union field is date.

Say it's the first half, before the union. I'd run:

```
SELECT * As Narration
    FROM 
        tblMaterialSheet tms 
        JOIN tblMaterialMaster tmm on tmm.Material_ID = tms.Material_ID
        JOIN tblCompanyLedger tcl on tcl.Pk_LedgerId = tms.Ledger_ID
    WHERE 
        tms.Material_ID = @MaterialId 
    AND 
        tms.isActive = 1
    AND
        ISDATE(tms.Material_Date) = 0
```

You might need to work outwards in your converting to see where it falls over, e.g., 
        AND
            ISDATE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), tms.Material_Date, 112))

Then you should have a good idea about the problem.

Incidentally,

CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Utilization_Date, 112))

looks very odd - what are you trying to achieve here by converting a date to varchar and back?

Comment: it will not converted to date time and throws an error so i am thinking to convert in varchar and then programming side i will convert to date so..

Comment: The thing is that the field starts off as a date. Do you need help converting it to the format you want?

Comment: no i dont want to convert now i have solved the problem by changing column order

Answer (score 1):

When you write a UNION or UNION ALL, You should make sure the following

1. No of Columns should be Same for Each Select Should Be same
2. Data Type of Column coming on the same position of each select Should be same

Suppose I have a column with character datatype for the first select and I'm trying to union it with a DateTime datatype, then I will get the error

```
SELECT 'ABCD'
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE()
```

This will throw the error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

because the datatypes do not match.

And this will cause another error:

```
SELECT 'ABCD',GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Like this:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

because the number of columns does not match.

So make sure that the datatypes match for each column in your UNION and if they does not match, try Cast or Convert

Comment: you can see table structure the materialdate i select have same datatype in tables